# NullPointerException in generating random numbers

Tags: java, random, nullpointerexception

I get a NullPointerException at line 14 the one that says:

```
points[i].x = new Random().nextInt(30);
```

My full Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPoints {
    public class Point {
         public int x;
         public int y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] points = new Point[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i].x = new Random().nextInt(30);
            points[i].y = new Random().nextInt(30);
            System.out.println(points[i].x + " " + points[i].y);
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `Point[] points = new Point[100];` it only allocates an array with room for `100` `Point` references (it doesn't allocate any `Point` instances). You need to allocate an instance for the index before you can access it, something like

```
Point[] points = new Point[100];
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = new Point(); //<-- like so.
```

Also, it would be better to reuse one `Random` created outside your array.

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

otherwise you reseed (twice) on every iteration. Meaning your numbers won't be very random.